# How to properly set up multiple environments in Google Cloud Build

Tags: c#, mongodb, google-cloud-build

I have not been able to find any information on how to properly set up multiple environments in the Google Cloud setup.  I recently created 3 different environments for my API which talks to a MongoDB instance.  My MongoDB server has 3 different databases on it, each matching the environment I want it to utilize.  My goal is to fill in the database connection strings to my MongoDB on build through the Google Cloud Build functionality.

On the code side, I have a Git repository with 3 separate branches (dev, qa, and prod).  These branches are currently deployed separately through the use of individual triggers on the Continuous build setup in Google Cloud, and this part works perfectly.  However, unless I can get each environment to use its specified database, having the 3 different environments is pointless.

To be concise, I need some information on how to add a database connection (specifically to a MongoDB database, but an example to any connection string would get me started) to a Google Cloud Build continuous build when it is triggered.

As a side note, I have seen plenty of Azure deployment information on using the built-in environment variables to build a c# application in the various build definitions you can set up in VS, but I have not seen the same functionality in Google Cloud, or at least not obvious enough for me to understand it.

Thank you for any information or help you can provide!

Comment: What about the concept of "Cloud Build" substitutions ... see:

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values

Comment: I've read just about all the documentation I can find in regards to Cloud Build, this one included.  However, if there is something in this page that is particularly helpful to my issue, I'm either too dense or too blind to see it.  If you understand how this could be utilized either in a build time yaml to configure my database connection string, or if you see a particular variable in there that would help, please elaborate =/

Comment: Thanks for persevering with the question.  You aren't dense at all :-)  It appears that Cloud Build allows "build time" environment variables or other dynamic properties using the concept they call "substitutions".  I had assumed that you could use these to pass in parameters or flags into the build to instruct the build on the type of build you want ... or pass in connection parameters.   Maybe use the trigger "$BRANCH_NAME" as the expression to use to select the connection string to your DB?